# Can't store timestamp in milliseconds into an integer

Tags: php, cql3

I have result of CQL query in `$result` and I want to print date time in string format from timestamp. My code is as follows:

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $mil = $row['datetime'];
    $seconds = $mil/1000;
    echo date("d/m/Y H:i:s", $seconds);
}
```

Output of :

```
echo $mil;
```

is correct millisecond value
 of timestamp

And output of :

```
echo (gettype($mil));
```

is 'object'.

As I need to divide millisecond value, I need millisecond value to be stored in integer variable. How to do that?

Comment: What is the value of `$mil` ?

Comment: 1518892182000 in my case

Comment: Check my answer that may solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

This just works fine

```
 echo date("d/m/Y H:i:s", (1518892182000/1000));
```

Use `var_dump($mil)` to check what datatype it is.

Make sure that you passing an integer value to `$mil` or typecast the value always to an integer.

```
$mil = (int) $row['datetime'];
```

Comment: `var_dump($mil)` gives output : object(Cassandra\Timestamp)#5 (3) { ["type"]=> object(Cassandra\Type\Scalar)#9 (1) { ["name"]=> string(9) "timestamp" } ["seconds"]=> int(1518892182) ["microseconds"]=> int(0) }

Comment: What is output?

Comment: thats an object of Cassandra, you need to parse the `seconds` from that and send it to `date()` function.

Comment: `echo (int) $mil;` gives output 1 instead of millisecond value

Comment: can you please help with parsing?

Comment: Because it is an object parse the seconds from that. what gives `$row['datetime']` ? any library?

Comment: Try `$row['datetime']->seconds` or `$row['datetime']->get('seconds')`

Comment: I am using cassandra php driver, which gave `$result` and on iterating it gave `$row`

Comment: Check above code works? or find how to parse the seconds from the cassendra timestamp object.

Comment: None of  `$row['datetime']->seconds` or `$row['datetime']->get('seconds')` worked.

Comment: https://github.com/datastax/php-driver/blob/master/ext/doc/Cassandra/Timestamp.php

https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/php-driver/1.3/api/Cassandra/class.Date/

check them it might help

Comment: `$dateTemp = $row['datetime']->toDateTime()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');` or `$dateTemp =  date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $row['datetime']->time());` worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

`$dateTemp =  date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $row['datetime']->time());`

or

`$dateTemp = $row['datetime']->toDateTime()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

works.